# Does running a console emulator will make the laptop hotter?

Tags: emulation

I have a gba rom, and a gba emulator which is  vba-m. If I do run the rom on the emulator will it cause an additional heat to the laptop? Will it be the same result on windows system?

Answer (score 1):

Any application that utilizes a lot of processing power will make your laptop hotter. Emulators usually use a lot of CPU power and it may result in making laptop hotter. Observe your CPU usage (use `top` or any other tool) while running emulation. Use `lm-sensors` to observe heat. **Results may vary depending on emulator and your hardware.**